# GDB not interrupting program immediately

Tags: c, linux, gdb, signals, i386

When debugging a large C application, I see strange behavior from `gdb`: 
I can always interrupt the program pressing `Ctrl+C`:

```
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x76f58964 in select () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81      in ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S
(gdb)
```

However, after a sufficient runtime of the program (like > 1 day), I cannot easily interrupt the program anymore.
When trying to interrupt the program with `Ctrl+C`, `gdb` just shows

```
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
```

and hangs there for several minutes up to hours.
If it takes longer than a few minutes, I usually open another terminal and kill `gdb` manually to be able to continue.

**Question: Is this expected behavior from `gdb`? Can I set an option to avoid this?**

Further details:

- The application is `FTL` (https://github.com/pi-hole/FTL)
- It is multi-threaded using `pthreads`
- During the waiting time after hitting `Ctrl+C`, `gdb` is at 100% CPU.

**Edit: Further details**

I ran `perf record -p $(pidof gdb)` for about 10 seconds while `gdb` was frozen. `perf report` returns:

```
90,82%  gdb      gdb                [.] find_thread_ptid                                                                                                   
 9,13%  gdb      gdb                [.] ptid_equal                                                                                                         
 0,02%  gdb      gdb                [.] iterate_over_threads                                                                                               
 0,01%  gdb      [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] run_timer_softirq                                                                                                  
 0,01%  gdb      gdb                [.] 0x0016a9a4                                                                                                         
 0,00%  gdb      gdb                [.] 0x0015a480                                                                                                         
 0,00%  gdb      gdb                [.] 0x0016a998                                                                                                         
 0,00%  gdb      gdb                [.] is_exited
```

After a few minutes, `gdb` finished and I ran `info threads` which still showed only three threads (as before):

```
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
  3    Thread 0x764b8460 (LWP 10114) "socket listener" 0x76f60260 in accept () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
  2    Thread 0x76cb8460 (LWP 10113) "loganalyzer" 0x76f58964 in select () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
* 1    Thread 0x76e65000 (LWP 10098) "pihole-FTL" 0x76f58964 in select () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
```

Comment: the file `signal.c`  seems to have some inconsistency with the way it is handling the `SIGINT` signal.  This may be related to the observed problem

Answer (score 0):

> gdb just shows ... and hangs there for several minutes up to hours.

A guess: your program creates, but does not properly join and terminate threads.

You can confirm or disprove this by running the program for a few hours, interrupting it with `Control-C`, and issuing `info threads` command.

On Linux, threads are just processes that happen to share virtual memory and file descriptors (and controlling terminal). When you hit `Control-C`, only *one* of your threads receives `SIGINT`.

In the default `all-stop` mode, GDB gets notified (by the kernel) that one thread has a pending `SIGINT`. GDB then needs to stop *all* the other threads of your process, and that can take non-trivial amount of time.

Not only that, but GDB may have to repeat this several times: while the threads were running, they may have created new threads, which now must be stopped as well.

Comment: There is at least one thread that exists the whole lifespan of the process (which listens for incoming connections on a socket). It is intended that this thread is never terminated as long as the process is running. I would expect `gdb` to "just" stop this thread as well (wherever it is at this moment). Interestingly enough, this works fine for short runtimes. Even for very long run times, there are not more threads according to `info threads`.

Comment: If there are no additional threads in `info threads`, then my guess is wrong and I have no idea what GDB is doing. You can run `perf record -p $pid-of-gdb` (while GDB is 100% busy), interrupt `perf` after 10s, then run `perf report` and update your question with the output. That output should allow for a better guess.

Comment: @MrD Your `perf` output *matches* my answer: GDB is iterating over threads. There must be many 100s or 1000s of them. What is the output from `ls /proc/$(pid-of-target)/task | wc -l`? (Note, here we want pid of the inferior (being debugged) process, not that of GDB.)

Comment: The result of `ls /proc/$(pidof pihole-FTL)/task | wc -l` is `3`

Comment: @MrD Interesting. Do you get any warnings from GDB about `libthread_db` being unavailable?

Comment: There are no `gdb` warnings at all (neither on start nor during runtime).

Comment: @MrD I've exhausted my guesses as to what may be happening. Try to come up with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, or wait for someone else, or debug GDB with itself to figure out why it's iterating over threads that aren't there.